# How to get data for a menu screen from server

Tags: java, android, html-post

So when i post to a server i get back html code of the webpage i am posting to. In that code i can find the information, like the name and other info that is needed for the menu screen. Do i extract that information from the html to put on the menu screen of the app or should there be a more simple way of getting the data from the server? Thanks

Comment: getting back HTML code? Why don't you define a simple web service which allow you to post and retrieve data from/to server.

Comment: do you know about Web services?

Comment: no, could you explain?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service

Comment: I know your problem man...sometimes we gets the html page contents in response....so if you are getting this then this is the error from server side...they are not sending data in proper way...please contact to your server side developer...

Comment: @Paresh what makes you think that a webservice would have access to data on the server of the requested page? It is not his server i suppose. If OP would make a webservice -on another server- that webservice had to parse the html source. But then the android app could do as well.

Comment: @greenapps That's what I guess! He hasn't posted enough detail for the issue he is facing!